# SQL slow subquery

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to retrieve data from a very large Audits table (millions of rows). So I need to make the query run as efficiently as possible.
First I am playing with a subquery to return the ObjectTypeId and use this to limit the query on the Audit table

This query is taking 4 minutes to run:

```
select distinct Audits.ObjectTypeID,  COUNT(*) as Count
from Audits as Audits
where Audits.ObjectTypeID = 
(select distinct ObjectType.ObjectTypeID from ObjectType where ObjectName = 'Data')
group by Audits.ObjectTypeID
```

If I default in the ObjectTypeID the query runs in 42 seconds

```
select distinct(Audits.ObjectTypeID), COUNT(*) as Count
from Audits 
where Audits.ObjectTypeID = 1
group by Audits.ObjectTypeID
```

But the subquery when run in isolation only takes only a second to run. So why should the first query take so long?

Comment: Can you provide, anonymized(?) output from SQL Profiler? or better provide the *actual*, not expected, execution plan?

Comment: Do you have indices on `ObjectType.ObjectName` and `Audits.ObjectTypeID`?

Comment: Is there more than one record that have the `ObjectName` of `Data`?  If not then you might take out the `DISTINCT` and see if that produces a more efficient plan.

Comment: How does `where Audits.ObjectTypeID = 
(select distinct ObjectType.ObjectTypeID from ObjectType where ObjectName = 'Data')` work?  There is only one returned record for this query... ever?  Coudn't you make this into a join instead rather than a subquery?

Comment: What is the slowest part of the execution plan of the slow query?

Comment: in first query in where condition you are using Distinct ObjectTypeID and searching on name scenario 'data'

Comment: and ofcourse where ObjectName = 'Data' have multiple id's it will produce more than one subquery error also

Comment: It's impossible to help without the *query plan* and knowing what indexes are defined. The `DISTINCT` subquery though doesn't help in anything and probably causes a huge delay. If you want audit records whose type is `Data`, just do an inner join between the tables. Distinct on a group is pointless as well.

Comment: Please post what indexes are defined in the two tables and the execution plan of the query. Run Query Analyzer on the query (after simplifying it) and see whether it proposes any new indexes

Comment: SHOWPLAN permission denied in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see three things that might help:

1. Pull the `ObjectTypeID` into a variable: since there should be only one value for it
2. Take out the `DISTINCT` on both queries since they should be unnecessary (the subquery should only have one value and you are grouping by that value in the outer query
3. Take out the GROUP BY since you are only querying for one `ObjectTypeID`

So the final query would be:

```
DECLARE @ObjectTypeID INT

SELECT @ObjectTypeID = (select ObjectType.ObjectTypeID 
                        from ObjectType 
                        where ObjectName = 'Data')

select Audits.ObjectTypeID,  COUNT(*) as Count
from Audits as Audits
where Audits.ObjectTypeID = @ObjectTypeID
```

If you are executing this as a single statement and not as a batch or stored procedure (meaning you can't use variables) thne you can keep the subquery:

```
select Audits.ObjectTypeID,  COUNT(*) as Count
from Audits as Audits
where Audits.ObjectTypeID = 
    (select ObjectType.ObjectTypeID 
     from ObjectType 
     where ObjectName = 'Data')
```

Comment: What about the case where there are more than 1 of the same `ObjectTypeID`?

Comment: Why not a simple join between the two tables? In fact, the second query is equivalent to just that. As for the first query, it's no different than what the query optimizer would do for the join case

Comment: @JohnOdom Then the original query in the question would fail.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos They might be equivalent, but the optimizer may create a different plan for a JOIN versus a query comparing to a single-value subquery.

Comment: Equivalent means they aren't different even from the optimizer's perspective. The optimizer will use statistics to determine that there are actually very few columns in the ObjectType table and use a hash join. In fact, this will run *faster* because the optimizer will avoid executing two queries and execute a single one instead.

Comment: Could you be able to optimize the 2nd select into a join with the 1st table or would that mess up the `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: Using the variable @ObjectTypeID speeds up the query superbly.

Comment: Removing the Distinct was sensible, but didnt really alter the speed. But why should the use of @ObjectTypeID speed things up so much?

Comment: Because it makes it more obvious to the compiler that it's searching for objects that all have the same value for `@ObjectTypeID`.  The others are logically equivalent but the compiler may not be determining that when developing a plan.

Comment: There are only 91 (unique) objecttypeIDs in the ObjectType table. So I really dont understand why this tiny subquery should slow down the overall query so much

Comment: @Juninho The subquery probably isn't the problem - it's how the compiler is choosing to search the main table that's the issue.  It may be deciding that it needs to scan the whole table rather than recognizing that it can just search the index to find all matching records.

Comment: @DStanley ok thanks, good info. so how do we influence the compiler, is it just trial and error? and is there a way to see what path the compiler has chosen? I cannot see (and have never seen!) an excecution plan - SHOWPLAN permission denied in database

Comment: `SHOWPLAN` is how you would see the plan the compiler produces.  You can influence the compiler by structuring your query in different ways, adding indexes where appropriate, and by trial and error.  Query optimization is a learned art.  Find yourself a good DBA and make him/her your best friend :)

Answer (score 1):

The part where you are getting the most performance hit could be this line:

```
where Audits.ObjectTypeID = 
(select distinct ObjectType.ObjectTypeID from ObjectType where ObjectName = 'Data')
```

You are actually calling the same query on every row of your table and it will search the ENTIRE `ObjectType` table and return the ENTIRE result of that subquery. This will be a big performance hit if your `ObjectType` table is HUGE. You could speed up that section of the query by using `EXISTS` so that it will return early once a result was found. Here is an example:

```
SELECT a.ObjectTypeID,  COUNT(*) as Count
FROM Audits a
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT ot.ObjectTypeID
    FROM ObjectType ot 
    WHERE ot.ObjectName = 'Data' AND ot.ObjectTypeID = a.ObjectTypeID
)
GROUP BY a.ObjectTypeID
```

Comment: The `DISTINCT` clause isn't needed. Grouping will only return a single row for each combination of the grouping fields

Comment: @JohnOdom Are you sure the subquery runs for every row?  I seem to remember that the compiler will recognize it as a single-value query (meaning it doesn't depend on any data in the outer query) and only execute it once, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @DStanley I'm not sure about how it works internally except for the query will get optimized (most of the time). If it returns the same data on every select then it could possibly get optimized out into being only called once. From my experience I noticed it calling on every row whenever the outer query contains more than 1 rows with different IDs. So this is more of a "just in case" query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Audits.ObjectTypeID,  COUNT(*) as Count
FROM Audits as Audits
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT ObjectTypeId, ObjectName FROM ObjectType 
 WHERE ObjectName = 'Data') as ObjectType ON Audits.ObjectTypeID = ObjectType.ObjectTypeID
GROUP BY Audits.ObjectTypeID
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Audits.ObjectTypeID,  COUNT(*) as Count
FROM Audits as Audits
INNER JOIN ObjectType as ObjectType ON Audits.ObjectTypeID = ObjectType.ObjectTypeID AND ObjectType.ObjectName = 'Data'
GROUP BY Audits.ObjectTypeID